# Pass groupBy parameter when using querydsl and spring-data exposed via a RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, querydsl

I am exploring QueryDsl, and in particular `@QuerydslPredicate` used on RestControllers for binding rest params to Querydsl Predicates. An example endpoint is given below:

```
@GetMapping
public Page<UserViewDTO> findAll(@QuerydslPredicate(root = User.class) Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
```

My request contains the following query params : `?username=user&page=0&size=10&sort=id,asc`. Is it possible to somehow pass a groupBy parameter? I have looked at the documentation but could not find a way to do so. Adding it to the query params is simply being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow pass a groupBy parameter?

No, it is not possible to pass groupBy parameter by QuerydslPredicate

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What would be a good way around it ? Extra endpoint custom param maybe ?

Comment: You need to use custom query here is example https://www.baeldung.com/querydsl-with-jpa-tutorial

Comment: Thanks. Yeah i know how to do it custom. It is a shame there is no out-of-the-box support for it.